# What is the differences between redirecting url using `httpd.conf` vs `.htaccess`?

Tags: apache, redirect, ubuntu, dns, subdomain

I google on the net and found two approaches to redirect incoming requests to apache in Ubuntu OS: 1) using `httpd.conf` and 2) using `.htaccess`.

I am confused. What are the differences between them?

Please share if you know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.htaccess`-file is meant to be used on shared servers where you don't have access to the primary Apache config files. It is generally a better idea to use `httpd.conf` or your site config rather than `.htaccess` if you can as this has a lower processing overhead (as far as I know, the `.htaccess`-file is parsed on each request), but both ways work fine.

Comment: +1. Small note: The rewrite rules (matching pattern) should also be modified a bit: URL in .htaccess is relative to the parent folder (e.g. for requested URL `example.com/help/kitten.php` the pattern should be matching  `help/kitten.php`) but in httpd.conf file the matching URL will be slightly different -- `/help/kitten.php` -- it includes leading slash. This difference has to be taken into account when transferring rules from one to another.